# Statistical dilemma teaser

Tags: probability

What's better statistically?
Taking a bet to win $£90$ at risk of losing $£10$ $(50/50)$,
taking a $50/50$ bet to win $£78$ or lose $£0$ (nothing), or
taking $£38$ and leave the bet altogether.

Comment: The economic theory of [utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility) describes the possibility of different preferences as to "better".  It might not be proportional, i.e. twice as much money might not produce twice as much "satisfaction" in a consumer.  Certainly this is the case with many goods and services which we exchange money for (twice as many shoes, for example, would not give most people twice the gratification).

Answer (score 3):

One criterion to use is to maximize the expected value of your earnings.

Let $ X_1,X_2,X_3 $ the earnings of each bet. Note that $ E[X_1] = 40, E[X_2] = 39, E[X_3] = 38 $.

Thus, according to this reasoning the first bet is the most favorable.

However, there are numerous objections to this approach.

Take a look at [Expected Utility Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_utility_hypothesis) and [Prospect Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospect_theory) for a first insight.